# React.js function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I recently saw a warning pop up on one of my projects saying that the React.createClass is now deprecated so I'm going through some of the code to make it compatible with the new recommendations.

One thing I've run into though is that one of my functions doesn't seem to fire like it used to.

```
class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();
        this.state = { content: "Initialize" }

    }

    changeScreen(newScreen) {

        // this fires
        alert("fired 01");

        // this function does not
        this.testFunc;

        var screen = "";

        switch(newScreen) {
            case "one":
                screen = "var01";
                break;
            case "two":
                screen = "var02";
                break;
            default:
                screen = "failed";
                break;
        }

    }

    testFunc() {
        alert("fired 02");
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <External.Element execChangeScreen={this.changeScreen} />
                {this.state.content}
            </div>
        );

    }

}

ReactDOM.render (
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I can't seem to get testFunc to fire, I've tried calling like follows

```
this.testFunc();
this.testFunc;
() => this.testFunc();
```

I'm not sure why but I think it may have something to do with this

*UPDATE*

All of the answers bellow are correct, the one I marked as accepted seems the clearest to me but thanks to everyone for their help

Comment: this.testFunc() is the proper way to call a function. this.testFunc is just a reference to the function. () => this.testFunc() is defining a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the `this` inside `changeScreen`

So use

```
<External.Element execChangeScreen={this.changeScreen.bind(this)} />
```

instead of

```
<External.Element execChangeScreen={this.changeScreen} />
```

and call your function

```
this.testFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you're not using `React.createClass`, you no longer have `this` automatically bound for you. The problem is at the point where `this.changeScreen` is called.

The simplest change to your code would be to bind it in the constructor:

```
this.changeScreen = this.changeScreen.bind(this);
```

Then make sure you're actually calling your function:

```
this.testFunc();
```

If you write `this.changeScreen.bind(this)` in your render method instead, you make a new copy of your function every time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Try testFunc = () => {} or bind it in the constructor method like this.testFunc = this.testFunc.bind(this)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to execute `changeScreen()` in the correct scope by using an arrow function syntax.

```
<External.Element execChangeScreen={() => this.changeScreen('one')} />
```

And inside the `changeScreen()` function, make sure to call testFunc correctly.

```
changeScreen(newScreen) {

    // this fires
    alert("fired 01");

    // this function does not
    this.testFunc();
    ...
}
```